# Image drawn on canvas not displayed in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

The following code with the 3 canvases works flawlessly with the latest IE and Mozilla FireFox. The third canvas (#drawingSurface3) fails on Google Chrome without any errors in the developer console. Even the lines are not drawn.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drawing lines in Canvas</title>
        <style>
            canvas {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="drawingSurface" width="300" height="300">
            <p>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</p>
        </canvas>
        <br />
        <canvas id="drawingSurface2" width="300" height="300">
            <p>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</p>
        </canvas>
        <br />
        <canvas id="drawingSurface3" width="300" height="300">
            <p>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</p>
        </canvas>

        <script src="scripts/modernzr 2-6-2.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingSurface");
                        var ctx;
                        if (ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")) {

                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
                            ctx.lineTo(75, 100);
                            ctx.lineTo(25, 100);
                            // ctx.stroke(); 
                            ctx.closePath();
                            ctx.stroke();
                            // ctx.fill();
                        }

                        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("drawingSurface2");
                        if (canvas2 && (ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d"))) {
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
                            ctx.lineTo(100, 300);
                            ctx.lineTo(150, 300);
                            ctx.lineTo(150, 155);
                            ctx.lineTo(205, 155);
                            ctx.lineTo(205, 100);
                            ctx.closePath();

                            ctx.fillStyle = "#0099ff";
                            ctx.fill();

                            ctx.lineWidth = 6;
                            ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                            ctx.strokeStyle = "#cccccc";
                            ctx.stroke();
                        }

                        var canvas3 = document.getElementById("drawingSurface3");
                        if (canvas3 && (ctx = canvas3.getContext("2d"))) {
                            var img = new Image();
                            img.onload = function () {
                                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                                //alert(ctx.getImageData());
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.moveTo(100, 125);
                                ctx.lineTo(150, 285);
                                ctx.lineTo(200, 233);
                                ctx.lineTo(250, 368);
                                ctx.lineTo(300, 402);
                                ctx.lineTo(350, 300);
                                ctx.lineTo(400, 90);
                                //ctx.closePath();

                                ctx.stroke();
                            };

                            img.src = "images/chartBackground.png";

                        }
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure that "images/chartBackground.png" is loaded?

Comment: @Gael Chrome "Network" developer tool tab identifies it as loaded.

Comment: Did you have an alert when "alert(ctx.getImageData());" was not commented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started fooling around in chrome://flags/

Disabling accelerated 2D canvas fixed the issue:

Option:

**Disable accelerated 2D canvas Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
Disables the use of the GPU to perform 2d canvas rendering and instead uses software rendering.**